# Cursor Window Too Big Android Sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, mobile, blob

I am developing an application in which I am to store large images e.g. of 2 MB, 3 MB in local Sqlite DB. But 2 MB cursor limit is causing exception. Is there any solution to this exception? Or If I should store image in chunks or parts in sqlite db. How should I achieve this?

Comment: Don't store the images in Database. That's just a bad practice. You can store the images in cache directory, private app directory, external storage or on the cloud. And then once you store the image, save the path / id in the database.

Comment: @Froyo Previously I am storing them in Internal Storage Which I also thinks is a good practise. But I am to store image inside Local DB like Sqlite because I want app user cannot see or change image outside my application.

Comment: @Froyo These images are captured from inside of my application and upload to client server from inside of my application.

Comment: The user can not see / modify the image if it's stored in private app directory or app cache. App cache can be cleaned up. You can use something like firebase or amazon buckets to store the images and the user won't be able to access it. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage

Comment: If the images are uploaded on the client server, you don't need to store in the database. You can store it in app cache because you will need the image only until you upload it.

Comment: @Froyo Thanks & App Cache sounds a good option. Can you please guide me a link or good library to use app cache in android apps?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202645/discussion-between-mohammad-aamir-and-froyo).

Answer (score -1):

Sqlite maybe unfit to do file storage directly. Perhaps you can store the file on DISK, and the URL / PATH in the sqlite database.

Comment: Previously I am storing them in Internal Storage Which I also thinks is a good practise. But I am to store image inside Local DB like Sqlite because I want app user cannot see or change image outside my application.

Comment: I used to work on a Android App Project, that uses a custom file wrapper to store images / videos which it does is to 'encrypt' the file data at some level.  If you do want to use Sqlite, maybe this would help: https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html